# Selecting newly inserted Core Data object causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableview that lists runners on a cross country team. If you select a runner, all of their individual races and times will be presented in a new tableview.

However, right after a runner is added, if that runner is selected, the app crashes when it should just open up to an empty tableview. Here's where I create a new runner, add it to the data source array, add it to Core Data, and update my tableview:

```
Runner *newRunner = [[Runner alloc] init];
//I set runner properties here.

[allRunners insertObject:newRunner atIndex:0];
//allRunners is used to populate the tableView.

NSManagedObject *savedRunner = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Runner" inManagedObjectContext:context];
//I set attributes here.

[appDelegate saveContext];

[self.myTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

And here's my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RacesOfRunner *vc = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RacesOfRunner"];

    NSManagedObject *selectedRunner = [selectedRunners objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *results = [GlobalFunctions getData:@"Result" pred:@"resultToRunner = %@" predArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: selectedRunner, nil] context:context];
    //executes fetch request and returns the results.

    vc.results = [results mutableCopy];
    vc.name = [selectedRunner valueForKey:@"name"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:false];

}
```

If I exit the view first, then come back to it, I can select the newly created runner just fine. What's going on? Here's the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '-[Runner longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702d2600'
```

The specific line causing the crash is the executeFetchRequest in my getData method:

```
+ (NSArray *) getData:(NSString *)entity pred:(NSString *)pred predArray:(NSArray *)predArray context:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entity];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:pred argumentArray:predArray]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!results) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching Employee objects: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Are you reloading the tableview after you add the item?

Comment: All I'm doing is using the insertRowsAtIndexPaths method to update the tableView.

Comment: It would help if you would say which specific line is causing this crash.

Comment: I added info on where the error is occuring